# A=N-P decomposition convergence to true solution

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I'm taking a numerical analysis course and we're looking at an iterative method for solving $Ax=b$ where $A$ is a square matrix, with a  $A=N-P$ decomposition with the formula

$$Nx^{k+1}=Px^k+b$$

Some qualifications for this decomposition to be "useful" are that

1) $N$ should be non-singular

2) The equation $Nx=h$  should be easy to solve, where $h=Px+b$

3) $||N^{-1}P||$ should be less than $1$ for some matrix norm

My question is about the last part. My book talks about picking $N$ to make this iterative method useful. Normally I take $N$ to be the diagonal of $A$ and that has always been sufficient. Is it possible that to pick an $N$ and a $P$ for this decomposition and have 3) fail (since 3) implies that this iteration converges to the true solution), but for another choice work (excluding where $P$ is the $0$ vector and visa-versa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, it is possible that for one choice of $N$ the iterations will converge to the solution and for some other not. For example, with $N=\alpha I$, $\alpha\neq 0$, we get a method commonly known as the (modified/damped/scaled) Richardson method. If the eigenvalues of $A$ are real and positive, it converges to the solution of $Ax=b$ *iff* $0<\alpha<2/\lambda_{\max}(A)$. Choosing an $\alpha$ outside of this interval leads to a divergent iteration.

P.S.: For a fixed $A$, you have to pick either $N$ or $P$. If one is given, the other is given from $A=N-P$.